# Can I call @Test method programmatically when TestNG.xml has list of classes only not methods?

Tags: java, selenium, testng

in `testng.xml` I call only class (not individual methods), so all three executes fine. Now i have one set of data for method 1 & 3 and for 2nd method I have two set of data. Now with my framework I call method2 for 2nd time using simple Java code. But since @Test for method 2 is not being called so report shows only one entry for method 2. So is there any way to handle this (so that entry is shown twice in TestNg report)

```
package scenarios;

public class L5_Miscellaneous {

    @AfterMethod
    public void catchscreenshot(ITestResult result) throws IOException, HeadlessException, AWTException{

    }

    @Test 
    public static void method1() {

    }

    @Test 
    public static void method2() {

    }

    @Test 
    public static void method3() {

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using Parameterized Test? We use similar functionality in JUnit to call give test multiple time with different set of parameters. Just found this tutorial for testng : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/testng/testng_parameterized_test.htm

Comment: Hi Girish, My problem is different. I have created a framework with webdriver+TestNG. So to make it real hybrid ..I am stuck at above point :(

Answer (score 0):

Try using `@DataProvider` to pass your parameters: http://testng.org/javadocs/org/testng/annotations/DataProvider.html

Data Provider basically runs your test multiple times based on the set you provide.

```
@Test(dataProvider="dataForMethod2")
public void method2(String x,String y) {
}

@DataProvider(name="dataForMethod2")
public static Object[][] sendDataForMethod2(){
  // set of data for method2
}
```